# Magento: Block rewriting works correctly in local, but in the server does not work

Tags: magento, overriding

I've rewritten a block in magento in my localhost then I transfer files from localhost to my server but overriden does not work.
All files in localhost and my server are similar.
I use xampp in localhost.

Comment: Is you localhost on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This often happens when the server is Linux/Unix based. Such servers are case-sensitive so ensure that you are using proper case in your block and config.xml file where the code for rewrite has been written.

Then after upload the file on server and clear all your caches and then check.

To cross-check if the issue is really due to case-sensitivity or not you can run the code on a local linux system.

Also make sure that proper file-permissions are assigned to your code files.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear/Refresh Cache.
2. Compile again if you have Compilation enabled.
3. If you have xtra apache modules, restart apache server.